# Fatal error: Class 'Phalcon\Http\Client\Request'

Tags: php, phalcon

Error on request

Fatal error: Class 'Phalcon\Http\Client\Request' not found in ControllerBase.php on line 41

```
use Phalcon\Http\Client\Request as CRequest;

 $provider = CRequest::getProvider();
            $provider->setBaseUri('http://localhost/testing');
```

Comment: How have you installed incubator? Composer? Have you added the autoloader?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to a copy of the incubator library files from the [Phalcon/Incubator](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon) github.  [Download](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/archive/master.zip) and copy all or just the HTTP directory to your /app/library/ folder. In your public/index.php, add $loader->registerNamespaces with the correct path to the incubator library.

```
$loader = new Phalcon\Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Phalcon' => APP_PATH . 'app/library/'
));

$loader->register();
```

Source: https://github.com/phalcon/incubator#autoloading-from-the-incubator

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?