# Phalcon url rest client

Tags: php, rest, phalcon

I have an URL HTTP with get parameter who returns a JSON object. Example :

http://example.com/params?param=X

It is possible with Phalcon to get the return of this url or I should use curl ?

Answer (score 0):

So far this is not included in the Phalcon project as you can see in [this answer](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2491/1-3-2-phalcon-http-client-adapter-curl) in the official forum but you can use the incubator library files. There is some info in the forum and also you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218158/fatal-error-class-phalcon-http-client-request) for more information.